# Alter output of script

Tags: linux, shell, timestamp

This code:

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//'
```

outputs something similar to:

```
112,915 people 10:44:54 PM Mar 18 2012
```

Can anyone help me make it so it will print out to look like:

```
3/18/2012 22:44:54 112,915 people
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not necessary to use the line continuation character if the line ends with the pipe symbol.  There's a style choice, and a good argument can be made that putting the pipe symbol at the start of the line is easier to read, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make your command this:

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%m\/%d\/%Y %H:%m:%S')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//' \
| awk '{print $3, $4, $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Hey, you've got Sed and Awk together in one shell pipeline.  Not bad!  And you never resort to anything heavyweight like Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

```
date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%m:%S'
```

gives you the date format you want, except that March is made "03" rather than "3".  If you really want March to be 3, then this works:

```
date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%m:%S' | sed -e 's/^0//'
```

And, if you want to make March 9 into 3/9 rather than 03/09, well, you can exercise Sed in any of several ways, but this one is as straightforward as any:

```
date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%m:%S' | sed -e 's/^0//' | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]]\+\/\)0/\1/'
```